# Unit to display for 00:00 minute:second format

Tags: labels, time, widget

What would be a way of making clear the distinction between 00:00 min:sec format and 00:00 hour:min format? Due to spacing constraints (driven by specific client specs regarding font sizes; this is an embedded HMI), I can neither use full format (00:00:00) nor is there space for a full min:sec / hour:min pseudo-unit.

I'm thinking of using "h" for the hour:min entries and "min" for the "min:sec" entries, but this not really intuitive.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, but sufficiently different that it's useful search fodder and **OP doesn't deserve downvotes**. Also the answers here are much more concise and generally better IMO.

Answer (score 11):

You can make something like :

```
11h32m
```

or

```
18m17s
```

Which is both short and pretty clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can always leave larger unit with one digit and one letter. 
0m:00 = minute & second 
0h:00 = hour & minute

Comment: you don't need the ":" when using a unit for time

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your target locale, `'` and `"` may be understood as abbreviations for seconds and minutes, but that can make `h` for hour look out of place:

```
00'00"
 1h00'
```

Perhaps use `:` as a separator for hours and minutes, and `'` as a separator for minutes and seconds?  Like this:

```
00'01  1 second
01:00  1 hour
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning locale. ' and " for mins and secs is traditional in (some? most?) anglophone locales *if* we know it's about time; otherwise it's far more common for feet and inches. But 3h30 is commonly used in (Canadian?) French for 3:30 am, not 3.5 hrs duration.  I'd recommend having a key somewhere on the screen, showing h:m:s or h:m or m:s to clarify.the format.

Comment: According to the question, it seems likely there's no space for a key either.  At least, that's my reading - I might be wrong.